# read more button jquery hiding only work on first element of div in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, togglebutton

hy, i have problem with this code it hide only first p of div, my div contain different headings and paragraphs, i want to hide all of first 180 characters but it hide only first li

```
<div class="product-short-description">
    <h5>Product Description</h5>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
<h5>Product Details</h5>
<p>Material: Aluminium</p>
<p>Warranty: One Year Warranty Guarantee</p>
<p>Original: China</p>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
<h5>Shipping Information</h5>

</ul>
</div>



function bbloomer_woocommerce_short_description_truncate_read_more() { 
   wc_enqueue_js('
      var show_char = 180;
      var ellipses = "... ";
      var content = $(".product-short-description").html();
      //var content = $(".product-short-description").text().length

      alert(content);


      if (content.length > show_char) {
         var a = content.substr(0, show_char);
         var b = content.substr(show_char - content.length);
         var html = a + "<div class=\'truncated\'>" + ellipses + "<a class=\'read-more\'>Read more</a></div><div class=\'truncated\' style=\'display:none\'>" + b + "</div>";
         $(".product-short-description").html(html);
      }
      $(".read-more").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(".product-short-description .truncated").toggle();
      });
   ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Display in PHP/HTML
WP Function => https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/

```
// PHP
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor';
$words = 2;
$more = ' … <a class=\'read-more\'>Read more</a>';
$excerpt = wp_trim_words( $text, $words, $more );
// $excerpt => Lorem ipsum … Read more
?>

<div class="product-short-description">
    <div class="excerpt">
        <?php echo $excerpt; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="truncated" style="display: none;">
        <?php echo $text; ?>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Action in JS

```
// JS
$(".read-more").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".product-short-description .truncated").toggle();
    $(".product-short-description .excerpt").toggle();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response, i dont have access to code all i have to do with jquery at frontend, that y i am using the code above you are seeing, i have to limit the paragraph at 140 characters including heading li div etc, if you can modification in my code it will great help.